# Accessing View variables from within functions in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Imagine a typical CakePHP application, in which a Controller passes various bits of data to the View using `$this->set` in the typical way:

```
class ThingsController extends AppController {
    function test() {
        $this->set('someparam', 5);
    }
}
```

If the corresponding View was to define and use a small helper function which outputs some HTML, is there any way to access that variable `$some_param` from within the function? I would have thought you could just access it as a global variable, but it always come out with the value `NULL`.

```
<?php
function helper_function() {
    global $someparam;
    echo var_dump($someparam); // Just prints NULL
}
?>
<h1>I am a View!</h1>
<?php helper_function(); ?>
```

To be honest, an even simpler use case is for the `helper_function` to be able to access things like the `$html` and `$javascript` helpers.

Comment: Unless you're *really* sure of what you're doing, I don't think you want to do things this way.  The reason to use cake (beyond Rapid Prototyping) is that it forces you to maintain compartmentalization and MVC.  What you're wanting to do violates the separation of concerns that is a major benefit of MVC.  I'd re-examine that this is how you actually want to do things.

Comment: +1 I'm with Travis on this, but see my answer.

Comment: Elements turned out to be exactly what I wanted here - accomplished exactly what I was aiming for with much less effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation you describe, you're going to be operating on the value after you've set it for the view. You may or may not be changing that value. Either way it could get confusing. It would be clearer - and make life easier when you've forgotten how this app works - to do something like

```
function test() {
    $myVar = 5;
    $this->helper_function($myVar);
    $this->set('some_param', $myVar);
}
```

As for accessing the helper functions, you can do this and there are times when there doesn't seem to be an alternative, but it is best avoided wherever possible as it breaks MVC.

This:

```
<h1>I am a View!</h1>
<?php helper_function(); ?>
```

just isn't right (assuming you have written the function in the controller). I would be calling that function in the view's controller action and passing the result out as a variable. Just try to remember, use the **controller** to *prepare* data for the view. Use the **view** to *display* the data.

Why not write your own helper? That would appear to be the way to solve your problems.

Comment: Maybe I'm just going about this all wrong, but all helper_function() does it print out some HTML, it's just to allow me to share some (mostly-identical) output between a couple of different views. Does that affect your answer?

Comment: I still think you should try to keep to the MVC. Perhaps an element would serve to write the HTML? Otherwise a helper as I said.

Comment: Read this: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1081/Elements - they are incredibly useful. I even do stuff like TinyMCE inits in an element.

Answer (score 1):

The view isn't in the global scope, and `$this->set()` doesn't make the variable available to the global scope.

If you want the variable available in `helper_function()`, you should just pass it in as an argument:

```
function helper_function( $arg )
{
    // Do stuff with $arg here
}
```

Accessing other helpers **is** something a custom helper can do:

```
class SomeHelper extends AppHelper 
{
    // Use the same syntax as the controller to add helpers to your custom helper
    var $helpers = array('Html','Javascript','Form');

    // Then in the methods, refer to these other helpers thus:
    function helper_function( $arg )
    {
        $out = '';
        $out .= $this->Html->div('class','text here');

        $this->Javascript->codeBlock("some jQuery here",array('inline'=>false));

        $out .= $this->Form->input('Model.fieldName',array('type'=>'hidden','value'=>$arg));

        return $out;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was afraid that was the answer :( I have a whole bunch of such variables, so this is going to be a bit of a pain

Answer (score 0):

use configure::read and write - 
sounds like they are some kind of configuration stuff in your app

this way you can access them anywhere you want

Comment: It's not configuration per se, it's data, like a list of country names or something like that

Comment: coming from the model/database?

Comment: in this case the above tip with passing vars to the helper function would be the most appropriate approach i guess.